# change a keystroke passing a hook(c/c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, hook, keystroke

is it possible to edit a keystroke using a winapi keyboard hook? well, not neccesary a keyboard hook but something like it..

i wanna do something like this:

user presses key 'A'

my function adds 1 to the virtual keycode (just an example)

the 'A' becomes an 'B'

and the 'B' is sent to the destination application

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a [Keyboardhook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997537.aspx). You install a filter and the filter function receives the virtual-key code and the state of the keyboard at the time of the keyboard hook. Then you can change the virtual-key code.

Additional Links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644984(VS.85).aspx

Comment: if i understand you correct, i've already tried this. do you mean just to change the virtal code in the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT received in the keyboardproc?

Comment: Yes, it works very well in exactly that way (I've done such a thing once). Note that you should have a _really_ good reason for doing that, as most people will find it objective if not malicious, and at least if you install a system-wide hook, antivirus software will likely raise an alert, too (application-wide hook does not seem to raise alerts, at least here).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by eating up the keystroke entered by user by applying keyboard hook.
and generating key_event of the character you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the virtual key value in the KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT directly.
Instead, return 1 in the hook function after you sendmessage with your modified virtual key value.