# C - How can I interact with a hidden window?

Tags: c, console, invisible, keylogger

My purpose is to make a keylogger and I don't want to just to copy the available codes out there around the internet because they can easily get caught by antivirus so I am writing one with an algorithm to make it seems like it is not recording the keystrokes. 
I wrote a program to make that while window is on top and it worked well. Then I used the following code to make it invisible:

```
HWND Stealth;
AllocConsole();
Stealth = FindWindowA("ConsoleWindowClass", NULL);
ShowWindow(Stealth,0);
```

but now the program can not capture the keystrokes because I cant anymore interact to the program.
Is there a code line that makes it possible to interact with a window in invisible while other window is on top?

Comment: So you want help writing a keylogger that won't be caught by anti-virus tools?  Why would anyone want to participate in that?

Comment: This sounds evil. I am off.

Comment: OP - please remove this question else it will be flagged to moderators as soliciting help with illegal/immoral activity.

Comment: @MartinJames A keylogger isn't illegal per se. At any rate, we are not here to judge to moral or legal aspects of questions.

Comment: @NullUserException if you wish to respond to questions of dubious legality/morality, on your head be it.  No lawyers gonna come after me.

Comment: @MartinJames, I think he commented as a moderator.

Answer (score 1):

Only the window that has focus will receive input. You can still capture keystrokes with [GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Not aware of any rule against this and similar questions have been well received: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954040/making-a-keylogger. In fact this question looks as if it is partially lifted from that one. You are misusing/misunderstanding the purpose of downvoting.

Comment: This is a grey area, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent/12688#12688

Comment: Neh, I don's see any gray here. More like red.

Comment: Perhaps you should get your eyes checked out.

Comment: The OP specifically aims to defeat antivirus software.  I wonder what is being written, then?